# Get External User email address by API

Tags: external-users

I'm trying to use SP API to retrieve list of users / email addresses of users a Folder is shared with.
I can only get the org. users with :

```
_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('FolderPath')/?$expand=ListItemAllFields/RoleAssignments/Member/Users
```

But this API is not returning the "External Users" this folder is shared with.

how can I get the external users?

Comment: How did you grant permissions to external users on folder? I can get the external users from above API if permissions are granted by breaking permissions inheritance on folder.

Comment: Sharing is granted by "sharing links" and the external user does not appear as user in the permissions view. there is no way to break inheritance for these users.